# How to avoid embedded (inline) images when saving outlook email attachments

Tags: c#, linq, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I have written a method to save outlook email attachments into hard disk and convert the file into Base64String. When I was saving the attachments, the embedded (inline) images also getting saved, even though they are not REAL attachments. I wanted to save only the real attachments. Then I modified the method as follows. But now I'm getting an error from the line of ".OfType()".

**Here is my code:**

```
private string GetBase64StringForAttachments(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Outlook.Attachments mailAttachments = mailItem.Attachments;
            
            try
            {                
                if (mailAttachments != null)
                {                    
                    Regex reg = new Regex(@"<img .+?>", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(mailItem.HTMLBody);

                    for (int i = 1; i <= mailAttachments.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Outlook.Attachment currentAttachment = mailAttachments[i];

                        bool isMatch = matches
                          .OfType<Match>()
                          .Select(m => m.Value)
                          .Where(s => s.IndexOf("cid:" + currentAttachment.FileName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                          .Any();

                        MessageBox.Show(currentAttachment.FileName + ": " + (isMatch ? "Inline Image" : "Attached Image"));

                        if (currentAttachment != null)
                        {
                            
                            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmddhhmmss");
                            string path = "C:\\test\\" + date + currentAttachment.FileName; //ToDo: Create Folder
                            currentAttachment.SaveAsFile(path);

                            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                            byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                            fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                            string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
                            builder.Append(encodedData).Append(",");

                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentAttachment);
                        }
                    }

                    if (builder.Length > 0)
                    {                        
                        string encodedAttachments = builder.ToString().Remove(builder.ToString().Length-1);
                        return builder.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                        return "";

                }
                else return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.DebugMessage(2, "Error in GetBase64StringForAttachments : in AddinModule " + ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailAttachments);                
            }
        }
```

**This is the Error Message:**

'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**What I need:**

1. I am not a big fan of LINQ. So, can you please advice me on this
2. Is there a better way of doing this?

   I already tried followed the suggested answers for these questions and they did not work for me

[Saving only the REAL attachments of an Outlook MailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424033/saving-only-the-real-attachments-of-an-outlook-mailitem)

[Don't save embed image that contain into attachements (like signature image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880346/dont-save-embed-image-that-contain-into-attachements-like-signature-image)

3. Is there a way to use Redemption for distinguishing the real attachments?

Comment: If you can't get the flags solutions to work, note that Microsoft changed the rules for flags and you have to use a different value for your check to make it work in Outlook 365. For details see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70823130/1657610.

Comment: @RegEdit, Thank you very much for your interest and the answer you shared with me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) exposes the [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`Hidden` property - it checks the `HTMLBody` to make sure the attachment is not used as an inline image.

Also note that you can access the attachment data using [RDOAtttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`AsArray` without saving the attachment as a file first.

```
Redemption.RDOSession rSession = new Redemption.RDOSession();
rSession.MAPIOBJECT = mailItem.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
Redemption.RDOMail rMail= rSession.GetRDOFolderFromOutlookObject(mailItem)
foreach (Redemption.RDOAttachment attach in rMail.Attachments)
{
  if ((attach.Type == Redemption.rdoAttachmentType.olByValue) && (!attach.Hidden))
  {
     attach.SaveAsFile(path);
  }
}
next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Attachment = MsgReader.Outlook.Storage.Attachment;

foreach (Attachment attachment in mailItem.Attachments.Where(a => ((Attachment)a).Hidden == false)) {
  // do whatever you want with the 'real' attachments.
}
```